# Android - How to place a view above all other activities, including of other apps (as Cubie does)

Tags: android, android-activity, tabs, widget, push-notification

Today I observed a functionality in an app named Cubie messenger that places a shortcut to the app and shows notification badges as you receive messages, you can drag this view to place it wherever you want in the screen or hide it if you drag it to the top.

I thought it was something new to jellybean but it also works in Android 2.3. I have been developing a while but have never seen anything similar:

The view stays above ALL content ALL the time while CUBIE app is alive (or is awaken via a push message), you can navigate through the desktop UI or even open other apps and you still see the CUBIE tab above all activities.

How can one achieve this behavior?

[image: cubie tab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html#TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY

Examples:

[Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-always-on-top-button-in-android)

[How to create a system overlay in Android which allows interaction with the windows below it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221892/how-to-create-a-system-overlay-in-android-which-allows-interaction-with-the-wind)

Comment: I hope your issue has already been solved but use this one it's easy to use. https://github.com/ericbhatti/floaties

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this library?

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1688531