# How to show a popup window on another actvity

Tags: android

I would like to display a message to the user for some asynchronous event. For example for an alarm expiration. I would like to display a popup or dialog that is displayed over any activity is the foreground at the moment (and this can be some other application activity) leaving the current activity in the backgound.

Is there a way to do so in Android?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you will be told that this is a bad thing to do, that it is against the Android way of doing things. Users do not like this. And that the Notification area is much better way to do this.

That said... there are ways to accomplish this...

---

A `Toast` will display no matter which activity is on the screen. So you could set up a background thread (or better a `Service`) that will display your information in a `Toast`. This might be good enough for you.

You may find it useful looking at [some `Toast` source code here](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2.1_r1/android/widget/Toast.java).

Also here is a nice page on how to create a custom `Toast` layout by replacing the default `View` with one of your own. (I have not done this, but it looks quite interesting):

- [Custom Toast Alert on androidexample.com](http://androidexample.com/Custom_Toast_Alert_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=87&aaid=110)

---

The alternative is much more difficult, and is to display a **System Overlay** window. Unfortunately you have to do quite a lot of work to get these set up properly.

Here are a few related questions that I used to get it working:

- [Creating a system overlay window (always on top)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4481226/creating-a-system-overlay-window-always-on-top)
- [System overlay android 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14695283/system-overlay-android-4-0)
- [How to create a system overlay in Android which allows interaction with the windows below it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14221892/how-to-create-a-system-overlay-in-android-which-allows-interaction-with-the-wind)

Each of these has links to many others - there are loads of System Overlay questions on here.

But things to remember:

1. In the old days, you could put a system overlay on top, and send
   touches through to the activity below. This is no longer possible,
   and so a lot of the answers are now out of date.
2. You may need to
       play around with the flags in the provided examples to get exactly
       the effect you are aiming for. Not all the examples use the same
       flags, so there are some subtle differences in how each solution
       works.

---

Then again, I also believe that the Notification area is a much better UI pattern to use, so I do recommend you try that first. It is easier to do, and most of us expect that type of behaviour rather than a pop-up.

The problem with a pop-up, is that it might interrupt a movie I'm watching. Or a game I'm playing.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, i had created two dialog for income event for background and foreground